# call bash script in script not found, directory is in $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have added a directory to my $PATH var to access all my bash scripts. The Problem is, wen i call them in another script they are not found. Only if i use the full path to there location they run in the script.

I tried two files to add the $PATH globally on the system /etc/profile.d/custom.sh and .bashrc, on both the same Problem.

All Scripts have a "#!/usr/bin/env bash" at the top.

In there another way, or have i missed something?

Comment: This should work. Add your new PATH directory in $HOME/.bashrc. Set binary perms (chmod +x). And after source that .bashrc (source /path/to/.bashrc), or open a new console, and try it again.

Comment: May be forgot to `source .bashrc` after you add entries

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.